# OLS estimator is consistent if the smallest eigenvalue of $X^TX$ goes to infinity as $n\to\infty$

Tags: least-squares, asymptotics, eigenvalues, consistency

I want to show that if $\lambda_{min}(X^T X)$ (i.e., the smallest eigenvalue of $X^TX$) goes to infinity as $n\to\infty$, then $\hat{\beta}$ is a consistent estimator of $\beta$.

My approach is the following:

Since $\hat{\beta} = \beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^Te$ where the linear model is given by $y = X\beta + e$, we can also rewrite the estimator as $$
\hat{\beta} = \beta + \left(\frac{1}{n}X^T X\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}X^Te\right).$$

Here is where I am currently stuck. It seems to make sense that if $\lambda_{min}(X^T X)$ goes to infinity, i.e., all eigenvalues of $X^TX$ goes to infinity asymptotically, $\left(\frac{1}{n}X^T X\right)^{-1}$ is zero. But I don't know how to show this precisely.

Comment: I think it might help to remember that X should be full rank and so is diagonalizable

Comment: it might help to use principal components analysis. Write $Z=XW$ where $W$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $X^TX$. That is $X^TXW=\Lambda W$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

Comment: Compute the variance of $\hat\beta:$ assuming $e$ has bounded variance, this will have an upper bound proportional to the eigenvalues of $(X^\prime X)^{-1}.$

Comment: In case someone don't know how to prove it yet, I computed the variance of $\hat{\beta}$ as @whuber advised, then you will have $\text{Var}(\hat{\beta} - \beta) \leq \sigma^2[\lambda_{min}(X^TX)]^{-1}I$ where $I$ is an identity matrix